# How to remove all headers from a HTTP request (GET/POST) from ajax call (browser/REST Client/Front end framework like angular)

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, http, frontend

I have to make an HTTP POST request from a client (Browser or POSTMAN or any frontend javascript based framework app) to a third party hardware which hosts a server at some PORT. The problem is the third party server considers all the headers as data. I just wanted to send HTTP POST request, removing all default headers and add body (text/plain) with data. I have tried with POSTMAN, an angular app etc., but whenever I send request from browser/any REST Client, Some default headers are attached to it. Kindly help me.

I have also tried passing 'undefined' or 'null' values to headers when making ajax/http post call, but still some headers are attached to it, as the third party hardware prints headers (considering it as data)

Comment: You can achieve this in Angular with the help of `HttpInterceptors`.

Comment: They are added by the browser, you cannot remove them

Comment: Which headers specifically are you wanting to remove and **why**?

Comment: How will a HTTP-based server work without at least the content-type/content-length headers? But if you absolutely want to do this you might have to add some sort of proxy server in front of the hardware which strips the headers.

Comment: First of all thanks for your response, guys. Actually the hardware hosts a server in some port to which we can stream data. The streamed data will be printed. We can use any server side language (C#, Java etc.,) to stream data. but my goal is to send data (via HTTP POST) from Browser based javascript app. from any front end client, if I send any request some provisional/default headers are added. The hardware considers this also as some form of data and it prints it.

Comment: I found a way to stream data via javascript (Stream API) but of no use. since javascript streams data only to the server it is hosted, we cannot stream to another server.

Comment: @SagarGuhe Thanks. I am researching about this.

Comment: @Phil Everything from headers and request properties like content type, user agent, connection etc.,

Comment: @Vasan - Goal is to achieve stream data to server from a front-end javascript based application. We can obviously write a C# Code to stream data to it but it makes the application platform dependent.

Comment: But you _cannot_ do this from frontend JS. Browser will ultimately add several headers (like Referer and UA) which cannot be removed because JS has no control over that.

Comment: I still don't understand **why**. What you're saying doesn't make sense

Comment: @Vasan Thanks, yes you are correct. I may need to find new way